# Checkmarx issue - Unsynchronized_Access_to_shared_data

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, synchronization, checkmarx

I am trying to resolve "**Unsynchronized_Access_to_shared_data**" issue. Further it says
**The concurrent process main found in the file src\main\java\demo\DemoApplication.java at line 1 influences the shared resource context in the file src\main\java\demo\DemoApplication.java at line 3. When performed concurrently, an unexpected race condition may occur.**

Below is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { //line 1
    mainThreadClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(); //line2
    context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args); //line3
}
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Why are you storing the `context` in a class variable? That shouldn't be needed and avoided.

Comment: It already exists in my project. I cannot modify it

Comment: Sure you can, else ignore the error and don't fix. Or fix it by removing the field (is it read from somewhere if not, delete it).

Comment: It is used in same class as shown...Do you understand what they are doing..............public static void restart() {
        ApplicationArguments args = context.getBean(ApplicationArguments.class);

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            context.close();
            context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args.getSourceArgs());
        });

        thread.setContextClassLoader(mainThreadClassLoader);
        thread.setDaemon(false);
        thread.start();
    }